# Error while creating CMK(column master key) in always encrypted

Tags: sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I am trying to explore SQL 2016 always encrypted feature but i am getting an error while generating new column master key, after entering name and selecting 'Windows Certificate Store-Current User' as key store through SSMS when i click on ok its throwing an error as  `object reference not set to an instance sql(sqlmanagerui)` 
 I googled it and checked the permission on registry but unable to solve this.

Comment: The problem was solved, but now again when im trying to generate CMK, facing same problem...any permanent solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of errors occur when there is something corrupt in windows, so please try repair sql server by running setup and also please do check if there is any pending reboot or an updates pending.
I have face same kind of problem and it was due to pending update so its something to deal with the registry

Comment: reboot didnt worked but yah repairing the sql solved the problem now i am able to create CMK and CEK..Thanks for your suggetion